# MATLAB SVM Image Classification using FOR Loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, classification, svm

I am loading eight images of database and finding the mean value for each image. After finding the mean values i need to pick a image for testing from this database and need to classify whether it is present in database or not. I am getting result only for last iteration. I couldn't able to get result for other iterations. Could anyone help me to get output and tell me where i am wrong.

the code is:

```
 for ix=1:8
    V='.jpg';
    ie=num2str(ix);
    Stc=strcat(ie,V);
    St=imread(Stc);
    figure(11),subplot(3,3,ix),imshow(St);
    title('original image');
    Nd(ix)=ndims(St);
    if Nd>2
        II=rgb2gray(St);
    end
    out1(ix)=mean2(St);
    end

I=uigetfile('.jpg');
I=imread(I);

out2=mean2(I);
fea=[out1;out2];
group=[1 2];
svmStruct = svmtrain(fea,group);
sample=fea;
class = svmclassify(svmStruct,sample);

if (class==1)  
    msgbox('Image is in database');
else
    msgbox('Image not in database');
end
```

I am getting error when i run this code as:

**?? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
Error in ==> chumm at 20
fea=[out1;out2];**

Please do help me as early as possible..

Comment: Did you define `out1` as a row vector before the loop starts? If so, that could be the problem. Try defining it as `out1 = zeros(8,1);` in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But even after initializing as you said the error remains.

Comment: What is `size(out1)` after the loops? and also `size(out2)` immediately after you calculate. it?

Comment: out1 is 8x1 and out out2 is 1x1.

Comment: i need to compare out1 values with out2 and if any one of the value in out1 matches with the value of out2. then the output should be as Image in database. How to code for this.

Comment: Is the error still there? That error shouldn't be there ..I think. For that comparison, just use - `any(out1==out2)`.

Comment: I have to declare that initialization before the loop starts right.. If so then the error exists still.

Comment: If i use Out1==Out2. the condition gets satisfied only for the last value. If i give other images as input i will not get the correct output as i needed.

Comment: If you dont mind can you work out in matlab and tell me the answer

Comment: could anyone help me.. please do guide me